# How can I use a dash to interrupt a quote with an action?

Tags: punctuation, dashes

A few times recently I've wanted to interrupt a line of dialogue with a non-dialogue interjection.  Here are some examples.

- Alice argued: "Nobody knows what happened to the eggs last night.  Nobody, except for --" she darted a suspicious glance at Bob -- "whoever *ate* them."
- Charles ran over to me, dodging projectiles.  "We must have really --" he ducked --"offended those monkeys!  What did you say to them?"

I'm pretty sure the punctuation here is terribly wrong.  How do I punctuate this properly?

Comment: The dash goes outside the quote marks.

Comment: A classic Wodehousean construction. And @Xanne is spot-on unless it indicates a pause in the speaking.

Comment: Nice sentences. As @Xanne said, the dashes go outside the quotes here. [Here's everything you need to know.](https://theeditorsblog.net/2018/04/08/when-a-comma-isnt-enough/)

Comment: Thanks! Anyone want to add an answer so I can accept it?